# Notify keyword not triggered in push-button widget

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm creating a widget out of an alist, and while the widgets (created via a for loop) are displaying correctly, the :notify directives are *never* processed. I can't explain it.

```
 (widget-create (get-data (author score num_comments title subreddit) a 
            (list 'push-button
              :action (lambda (&rest ignore)
                    (message "test"))
              :post-id n
              :reddit-author author
              :reddit-score score
              :reddit-comments num_comments
              :reddit-title title
              :reddit-subreddit subreddit
              (format "%s" author))))
```

I also tried to in create a widget from scratch and the notify directive was also ignored;

```
 (widget-create 'push-button 
   :notify (lambda (&rest ignore) 
             (message "trigger")) 
   "click me")
```

I also read that the *action* keyword does something similar to notify, so I tried it. Nothing happened.

Could anyone point in me the right direction?

GNU Emacs 24.1.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.2.9200) of 2012-06-10 on MARVIN

Comment: I assume you're calling `widget-setup` at the end.

Comment: @DiegoSevilla, yes I am.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Turns out you have to set they key map to widget's one in order for this feature to work. Makes sense, I simply hadn't seen this part of the documentation. If you are using your own keymap, then you can make widget's keymap it's parent, like so:

```
(defvar your-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (set-keymap-parent map widget-keymap)
    (define-key map "q" 'your-quit)
    map)
  "Custom key map")
```